# AddThis plugin doesn't work in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, addthis

My task was to create modal window with content (some details about game) which will be opened on row click (on Search page : 1 row - 1 game). Content i try to get from aspx page. Cause this page are inherited from Master page where all scripts are attached (when i open this modal all scripts were loaded again and this broke page layout) i create second Master page only for this modal window where are included just necessary file, scripts etc.

Problem : everything is fine exept one thing : on Page Searcg.aspx and in modal window i use [addThis plugin](http://www.addthis.com/). On Search page everything is initialized, but when i open modal - addThis plugin doesn't loaded needed icons etc.

How i use plugin :

```
                    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
                    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
                        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_print"></a>
                        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { "data_track_clickback": true };</script>
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=username"></script>
                    </div>
                    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dynamically loading the buttons within the modal window, you'll need to call addthis.init() and/or addthis.toolbox() to render the div. Here's some more information from the AddThis website:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1293805-using-addthis-asynchronously